# MainMenu.xib with dispositioned main window

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

Each time I create any type of cocoa project (document-based, with core-data and/or spotlight importer) and open MainMenu.xib, I get a warning sign in bottom right object palette window corner saying that window is out of screen bounds. Why is this so? Any remedy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get a warning sign in bottom right object palette window corner saying that window is out of screen bounds. Why is this so?

Because the window falls at least partially outside the screen bounds.

> Any remedy?

Put it completely within the screen bounds. Select the window and use the Content Size & Position section of the Size (⌘3) inspector to move it.

Simply dragging the window by its title bar will not help, since that position is only for display in IB; it doesn't affect the window that will appear in your app, which is what the warning is about. You need to use the Size inspector.

Comment: Thanks, but I figured that much .) wanted to know if there's any remedy for creating new project with already properly positioned main window.

Comment: That's just how it is in the xib in the template. You'll have to adjust it every time, make your own modified template, or buy a bigger monitor. You may also want to file a bug: https://bugreport.apple.com/

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar problem when I had a second monitor connected to my MBP.
When the second monitor was set to a low resolution (I think it was 1024x768), Interface Builder came up with that particular warning. (Although the window did fit between the main menu and the Dock).

Comment: So can it be side effect from having second monitor?

Comment: I only noticed that behavior when my second monitor was connected, set as main monitor AND set to a low resolution.